# How to add a control to a added tab C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple application that keeps track of coins.  I have a button that creates a new tab in a tabcontrol container.  I am wanting to add some textboxes to the newly added tabs.  The below code adds a textbox to my main tab called "Control".  I have tried playing around with that field, but it always adds it to the main page called control.  How would I do this?  I have the following code:

```
           string name = txtName.Text;


            //validate information
            try { }
            catch { }

            //create new tab
            string title = name;
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);


            //Add text boxes

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 75);
                tb.Name = "TextBoxName";
                tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 20);
                Control.Controls.Add(tb);

            //put data inside of textboxes

                tb.Text = txtCoin.Text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the text box to the controls collection of the new tab:

```
//Control.Controls.Add(tb); //Replace this line
myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`Control.Controls.Add(tb)`

to

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Last().Controls.Add(tb)
```

```
tabControl1.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>().Last().Controls.Add(tb)
```

Comment: That won't compile; `TabPages` isn't an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: TabPages is a TabPageCollection object: `public class TabControl.TabPageCollection : IList, ICollection,
   IEnumerable`

Comment: Exactly.  It's not `IEnumerable<T>`, so the only LINQ methods available are `Cast<T>` and `OfType<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks Aha, got it. so it would be `tabControl1.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>().Last().Controls.Add(tb)`. Actually it's easier to use `myTabPage` I didn't note that in OP code when I posted the answer.

Comment: Works, but since the other code is similar, I tend to believe simple code = better code (less problems).